# Jmeter showing inconsistent results when bean shell listener added

Tags: jmeter, listener, beanshell

I am trying to hit an API using `Jmeter` distributed environment.

- When applied a load of 1500 concurrent users to 7 machines [i.e. 1500
  X 7 = 10500 concurrent users]. Jmeter gave an error of 12% approx and
  average response time of ~850ms.
- but when I added a blank 'BEAN SHELL LISTENER', the response time can
  back to ~220ms with 0% error (with same load i.e. 1500 x 7 clients
  machines).

Can someone help me understand what Bean Shell Listener is doing here and how the response and error count is dropped when used Bean Shell Listener.

**Additional Info:** The api is running on a cloud box (T2 Large).

Answer (score 0):

Blank Beanshell Listener does nothing apart from consuming resources required to initialise Beanshell scripting engine and evaluate the script (no matter if it is blank)

So my expectation is that by adding a Beanshell listener you added an extra work for JMeter so it wasted CPU time and memory for processing an entity which does nothing therefore the real delivered load was less (you can check it by looking at Throughput metric)

All listeners are **very** resource intensive so recommended way of running a JMeter test is [non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) with [all listeners disabled or even deleted](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing).

Comment: I was expecting the same,(it will increase the processing time resulting in increased average response time, BUT in my case the average response time got better (reduced from ~850 ms to ~220ms). The other thing which i observed was error count reduced to 0 which is weird.